# Thre are two seperate types of data in a txt file, how do i use pandas to interate each line and add the corresponding data

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I recently acquired data for my local gym and I'm attempting to normalize the data so that a "gym signup" object can be created, which contains all the people that signed up for that session.

The text file looks like this:
https://pastebin.com/YcnSJiA7

```
Sep 30th  '20 at 9:00AM Until Sep 30th  '20 at 10:00AM
JD  John Doe    
AW  Alice Wonderland    
IM  Iron Man
Sep 30th  '20 at 8:00AM Until Sep 30th  '20 at 9:00AM
JD  John Doe    
AW  Alice Wonderland    
IM  Iron Man
```

I've been able to use pandas to separate the signs ups by column[initials of name, name] but I have no idea how to detect when a line corresponds to the time slot and not to a person signing up.

So after the program runs, every line should consist of the columns [initials of name, name, timeslot]

the easiest way for me to work with this data would be in this format,

```
JD  John Doe    Sep 30th  '20 at 9:00AM Until Sep 30th  '20 at 10:00AM
AW  Alice Wonderland    Sep 30th  '20 at 9:00AM Until Sep 30th  '20 at 10:00AM
IM  Iron Man    Sep 30th  '20 at 9:00AM Until Sep 30th  '20 at 10:00AM
JD  John Doe    Sep 30th  '20 at 8:00AM Until Sep 30th  '20 at 9:00AM
AW  Alice Wonderland    Sep 30th  '20 at 8:00AM Until Sep 30th  '20 at 9:00AM
IM  Iron Man      Sep 30th  '20 at 8:00AM Until Sep 30th  '20 at 9:00AM
```

I attempted to iterate through every line and once a time slot line comes up, then I append that line to the next ones, until a new time slot appears.

```
def testSort():
    with open("1-weak-gym.txt") as fp:
        id= []
        totalSheet=[]
        timeSlot = []
        lastLine=[]
        for ln in fp:
            if ln.startswith("Sep"): ##this is a time slot
                timeSlot.clear()
                timeSlot.append(ln[0:]) ##save that time slot as the lastDate variable
            else:
                if (timeSlot):
                    totalSheet.append(timeSlot) ##append the time slot
                    totalSheet.append(ln[0:]) ##append the name line
                else:
                    print('Hello eror')

    print(totalSheet, file=open("newOuput.txt","a"))
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.
Note that off-site links are not acceptable.  Your posted code defines a function that is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach ( if you have a strong pattern with time at the end of the headers rows):

```
import re

def is_time_format(s):
    time_re = re.compile(r'\b((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9])([AaPp][Mm]))')
    return bool(time_re.match(s))

with open("1-weak-gym.txt") as fp:
    new_lines = []
    extra_info = ''
    for line in fp:
        last_bit = line.split(' ')[-1]
        if is_time_format(last_bit):
            extra_info = line
            continue
        else:
            new_lines.append(line.rstrip() + '\t' + extra_info)

open("newOutput", 'w').writelines(new_lines)
```

Then you will get a file in the proper format.

Comment: @"joao sallescould" you help answer,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64555960/cleaning-a-csv-file-after-scraping-it ? The same format but a little messier of code